# Update field and $push to array in one query in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have this code:

```
db.basket.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId(data['basket_id'])},
    {
        'total': round(total, 2),
        '$push': {
            products': {
                'prod_id': data['prod_id'],
                'price': price,
                'amount': data['amount']
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Running this query gives me an error:

```
uncaught exception: field names cannot start with $ [$push]
```

Is it possible to update field in database object and push new object into array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed to use [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) for your single value update. Otherwise this is attempting to mix the form of update with a plain object and a "update" operator. MongoDB thinks this is just a plain object update and thus tells you that "$push" is illegal for a field name:

```
db.basket.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId(data['basket_id'])},
    {
        '$set': { 'total': round(total, 2) },
        '$push': {
            products': {
                'prod_id': data['prod_id'],
                'price': price,
                'amount': data['amount']
            }
        }
    }
)
```

So using the correct operator here let's MongoDB know what you are trying to do and processes it correctly. Other [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) work in the same way. Only where all together.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I knew that there should be some trick.